# Is Glazedlists dead?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, glazedlists

I've tried to download Glazedlists and virtually all useful links are dead (404 or go to empty/meaningless locations).  I've googled about it and no mention of the project being abandoned, so I feel like I'm in the twilight zone - is it just me?

For example, I started at http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/ and following links from there usually take me to Java.net. I can browse source online only (1 file at a time out of 'lots and lots' (didn't count 'em)). All download links there, SVN link, etc don't work for Glazedlists project.

Anybody know the status of Glazedlists please?

Comment: java.net had a major reorganization lately.    You can see how it affected the Hudson project here: http://kohsuke.org/2010/11/23/hudson-java-net-migration-status-update/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an update by the team about the migration to the new java.net (posted feb 27th 2011).

http://sites.google.com/site/glazedlists/Home/whats-new/glazedlistsjavanetmigration

Unfortunately java.net is slow/down currently.

Comment: This link provides a page with download links that will let you download all source zipped into one file.
Specifically: http://java.net/downloads/glazedlists/

Answer (score 3):

This might be quite an old question, but the [github repo](https://github.com/glazedlists/glazedlists) of the glazedlists project seems to be very active. And the [official site up and alive](http://www.glazedlists.com/)

Also there is a port of the project to work with a java web framework called vaadin.

Comment: Clarification: [the Vaadin library](http://vaadin.com/addon/glazedlists-vaadin-container) is an adapter rather than a port. It makes the existing GL library classes play nice with standard Vaadin data models.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is Subversion access available at http://java.net/projects/glazedlists/sources/svn/show (download link is https://java.net/svn/glazedlists~svn/trunk -- it does not appear to work without authentication from a Web browser).  The new home page appears to be http://java.net/projects/glazedlists -- there are non-spam mailing list posts from this month.

Comment: I tried the https URL under "Checkout URL". It redirects and results in a 404.

Comment: @John: they appear to be transitioning between Web sites, so lots of things are missing.  You might need to send a mail to their mailing list (that does seem to be working, at least from the archives).

Comment: @John: I found a better checkout URL that works; try the one in my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

try http://sites.google.com/site/glazedlists/Home. The most recent activity there is September 2010.

the svn repo at http://java.net/projects/glazedlists/sources can be accessed with no login

Comment: That doesn't have working download links, though (it seems to point to the same ones as the publicobject.com site).

Comment: you are right. the download links there don't work. The SVN does, however

Comment: I had tried http://sites.google.com/site/glazedlists/Home (went in circles). Usually, for downloads, the links take you back to Java.net. I tried the SVN link, and get a login dialog. I enter the same userID/pswd as my Java.net account and it's rejected. Am I required to register for SVN access separately?

Comment: the svn is up to version 0.9.5 apparently. The instructions for building are on the google site somewhere, so it isnt impossible to get the jar file. SVN access is open. There was no login box for me. try checking out from https://svn.java.net/svn/glazedlists~svn

Comment: OK, I better go take a look at online help for SVN access. Thanks for your help.

Comment: try tortoiseSVN to download it. You can also fire up the repo-browser in tortoise to browse a remote repository without downloading anything.